# Redirect all subfolder requests to a specific folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect all the requests to a specific folder inside my domain.

For example:

`www.example.com/whatever` needs to be redirected to `www.example.com/specifiedfolder` by preserving the requested address `www.example.com/whatever`.

I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com\xxx
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/com1/$1 [R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method which will redirect as you expect

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/specifiedfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /specifiedfolder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: sorry, i mean whatever we type after domain.

Comment: Sorry i am not able to access root

Comment: hi, how can i add two conditions to this

Comment: Thats not two conditions one is condition and one is rewrite rule

Comment: Hi, i need to prevent redirect when empty and admin

Comment: admin prevented, but for root, we need to give empty condition

Answer (score 2):

You can use this rule to rewrite (not redirect) from root to another folder:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^specifiedfolder/ /specifiedfolder%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Make sure this rule is placed in site root .htaccess not in any sub-directory.

Comment: Sorry, its not working... i tried like 
RewriteRule ^mydomain.loc(/.*)?$ /specifiedfolder$1 [L,NC]

Comment: What is `mydomain.loc`? What URL you are entering in browser to test and where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: http://mydomain.loc/anything and i need to launch to the index of http://mydomain.loc/specifiedfolder

Comment: Then your rule should be: `RewriteRule ^anything(/.*)?$ /specifiedfolder$1 [L,NC]`. Remeber that `RewriteRule` doesn't match host/domain name and make sure this rule first rule in site root .htaccess.

Comment: sorry i mean    
mydomain.loc/{anything}

Comment: ok answer edited. Also your accepted answer will cause infinite looping unless there is a .htaccess in `specifiedfolder/`

Comment: That's what saved you otherwise unconditional rewrite to a different folder will cause 500 internal error due to infinite looping.

Comment: Thanks for your info